# Um exercício proposto em PYTHON de loop infinito

Tags: python, loop, while

OLÁ, estou tentando resolver a questão abaixo, mas não consigo fazer funcionar o LOOP, já que o exercício pede que mesmo após escolher um tipo de média, a instrução volte pedindo infinitamente a mesma coisa:

***Implemente um script python com:

- uma função que recebe três valores numéricos e um carácter por parâmetro .
- se o carácter passado como argumento for 'A' ou 'a', a função retorna o cálculo da média aritmética dos valores numéricos
- se o carácter passado como argumento for 'P' ou 'p', a função retorna o cálculo da média ponderada (pesos: 5, 3 e 2) dos valores numéricos;
- e se o carácter passado como argumento for for 'H' ou 'h', a função retorna a média harmônica dos valores numéricos.
- este script deve interagir com o usuário consultando os três valores e também qual tipo de média o usuário deseja calcular.
- este script deve ser interativo, ou seja, ele deve consultar se o usuário deseja realizar um novo calculo ao final de cada execução e, caso a resposta seja afirmativa, repetir o processo.***

---

O meu código referente a questão acima:

```
    num1=float(input('Digite um primeiro número: ')) 
    num2=float(input('Digite um segundo número: ')) 
    num3=float(input('Digite um terceiro número: '))
        
        #FORMULAS DAS MEDIAS: 
    med_arit=((num1 + num2 + num3) / 3) 
    med_harm=((1/num1 + 1/num2 + 1/num3)/3) 
    med_pond=((num1*5 + num2*3 + num3*2) / 10)
        
    print('Os números inseridos respectivamente são: {:.0f}, {:.0f} e {:.0f}.'.format(num1,num2,num3)) print('================================', '\n')
        
    med=str(input('Agora para saber as MÉDIAS: 
\nARITMÉTICA, digite [A]; 
\nHARMÔNICA digite [H]'
\nPONDERADA digite [P]' 
\nDIGITE A LETRA DA MÉDIA DESEJADA: '))
        
        
        while True:
            try:
            if med in 'Aa':
                print('A MÉDIA ARITMÉTICA é igual a ', med_arit)
                break
            elif med in "Hh":
                print('A MÉDIA HARMÔNICA é igual a ', med_harm)
                break
            elif med in "Pp":
                print('A MÉDIA PONDERADA é igual a ',med_pond)
                break
            else:
                print(input('Voçê inseriu um valor errado, tente novamente: '))
```

Answer (score 0):

Podemos criar uma função com os parâmetros do cálculo e criar uma condição para sair do programa no fim.

```
def media(num1, num2, num3, med):
    if med in 'Aa':
        med_arit=((num1 + num2 + num3) / 3) 
        return 'A MÉDIA ARITMÉTICA é igual a ' + str(med_arit)
    elif med in "Hh":
        med_harm=((1/num1 + 1/num2 + 1/num3)/3) 
        return 'A MÉDIA HARMÔNICA é igual a ' + str(med_harm)
    elif med in "Pp":
        med_pond=((num1*5 + num2*3 + num3*2) / 10)
        return 'A MÉDIA PONDERADA é igual a ' + str(med_pond)
    else:
        return 'Voçê inseriu um valor errado, tente novamente: '
    
med = ""
while med.lower() != "n":
    med=str(input('''Agora para saber as MÉDIAS: 
    \nARITMÉTICA, digite [A] 
    \nHARMÔNICA digite [H]
    \nPONDERADA digite [P]
    \nDIGITE A LETRA DESEJADA: '''))

    num1=float(input('Digite um primeiro número: ')) 
    num2=float(input('Digite um segundo número: ')) 
    num3=float(input('Digite um terceiro número: '))
    print('Os números inseridos respectivamente são: {:.0f}, {:.0f} e {:.0f}.'.format(num1,num2,num3)) 
    print('================================', '\n')

    print(media(num1, num2, num3, med))
    print('================================', '\n')
    med = input("Deseja efetuar um novo cálculo? [S]im ou [N]ão: ")
    print('================================', '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma interessante para resolver esta questão é implementando uma classe englobando todas as médias que desejamos. Desta forma podemos implementar o seguinte código:

```
class Medias:
    def __init__(self, num1, num2, num3):
        self.v1, self.v2, self.v3 = num1, num2, num3

    def media_aritmetica(self):
        return (self.v1 + self.v2 + self.v3) / 3

    def media_ponderada(self):
        return ((self.v1 * 5) + (self.v2 * 3) + (self.v3 * 2)) / 10

    def media_harmonica(self):
        return (1 / self.v1 + 1 / self.v2 + 1 / self.v3) / 3


while True:
    numero_1 = float(input('Digite o primeiro valor: '))
    numero_2 = float(input('Digite o segundo valor: '))
    numero_3 = float(input('Digite o terceiro valor: '))

    medias = Medias(numero_1, numero_2, numero_3)

    while (me := input('Média Aritmética, Ponderada ou Harmônica? [A/P/H] ').upper()) \
            not in {'A', 'P', 'H'}:
        print('Valor INVÁLIDO!')

    if me == 'A':
        m_aritmetica = medias.media_aritmetica()
        print(f'A média aritmética é: {m_aritmetica:.2f}')
    elif me == 'P':
        m_ponderada = medias.media_ponderada()
        print(f'A média ponderada é: {m_ponderada:.2f}')
    else:
        m_harmonica = medias.media_harmonica()
        print(f'A média harmônica é: {m_harmonica:.2f}')

    while (resp := input('Desejas realizar outro cálculo? [S/N] ').upper()) not in {'S', 'N'}:
        print('Valor INVÁLIDO!')
    if resp == 'N':
        break
```

Observe que quando executamos o referido código devemos digitar cada um dos três valores e pressionar <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Em seguida será instanciada a classe **Medias**. Posteriormente, recebemos a seguinte mensagem:

```
Média Aritmética, Ponderada ou Harmônica? [A/P/H]
```

Nesse momento devemos escolher uma das médias sugeridas. Para isso, devemos digitar a **primeira letra** da média desejada. Em seguida, será verificado se a expressão atribuída à variável **me** corresponde a uma das três letras - A, P ou H. Se a expressão atribuída à variável **me** **NÃO** for uma dessas três letras, seremos novamente solicitado uma das opções. Caso contrário, será verificada qual letra foi digitada e, de acordo com a letra digitada, será chamado um método específico, pertencente à classe **Medias**.

Exemplo: Se a letra digitada for **a** ou **A**, será chamado o método **media_aritmetica()** e, consequentemente, será realizado o cálculo da média aritmética, sendo, posteriormente, exibido o resultado com duas casa decimais.

Tendo realizado o primeiro cálculo o script nos perguntará:

```
Desejas realizar outro cálculo? [S/N]
```

Nesse momento devemos digitar **s** ou **S** para **SIM** ou **n** ou **N** para **NÃO**.
Caso digitarmos **s ou S** o script será novamente executado nos solicitando novamente os três valores e, consequentemente o nova operação. Caso Digitarmos **n ou N**, o script encerra sua execução.